# Magento theme integration

Tags: magento-2.0

Hi I'm trying to figure out theme implementation in Magento. It's my first Magento Community Edition installation and obviously first theme that I try.
The problem I'm ecnoutering is
my footer.phtml in not showing in front-end  it showing some default footer  .And one more thing, In screensort u'll see the default content is coming i want to disable it "**CMS homepage content goes here**"

**here is  file structure:**

```
/var/www/projects/Magento_mag/app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mag/Magento_Theme/templates/html
```

Here i have created all html files in  template. My header and content part is showing in front-end but footer part is not showing 
here is screensort and footer html

[image]

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<!-- footer container -->
    <div class="footer-container">
      <div class="footer">
        <div class="footerCol">



        </div>

        <!-- footer botom bar -->
        <address class="copyright">
        By entering this site, at vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime.
        </address>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- white shadow wrapper end here --> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have just dumped the theme files in the magento folder but you have not set the demo content of the theme.
If you get the demo content with the theme you just have to read the document which comes with theme and follow the instructions and set the cms page as per requirement.
If the demo content is not provided then you have can disble the cms content on home page from admin panel.
Login in admin panel -> Navigate to cms -> pages -> search for the page which have the content displaying in home page and then disable it.

If you need any other help please let me know. If you can give me access I can have look into it.

Comment: Hi, thats not a solution i have alredy did this!! As i want to remind you its a magento2 that i have asked question.if i desable it then it is giving me saome other default text.. --There was no Home CMS page configured or found.-- And i created theme to follow documentation did't dumped.Here is theme path         /var/www/projects/Magento_mag/app/design/frontend/Mypackage/mag/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtm
header is showing as well content is also showing but my footer is not showing..could you expalin me what the exact issue or m doing something wrong